# How to make Unit Testing for a UITextField to see if is empty

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, swift4

I try to implement a Unit Test for a textfield to check if that textfield is empty but I'm getting the error `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. And I'm using Guard but I don'w know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
class AdminPanelViewController: UITableViewController {

// Func to insert data from TextFields into CoreData
    func insertProduct(){

        guard let productName = productNameTextfield.text, productName != "" else{
            SCLAlertView().showError(Constants.nameRequired, subTitle: Constants.messageNameRequired)
            return
        }
        guard let productCategory = productCategoryTextField.text, productCategory != "" else{
            SCLAlertView().showError(Constants.categoryRequired, subTitle: Constants.messageCategoryRequired)
            return
        }
        guard let productPrice = productPriceTextfield.text, productPrice != "" else{
            SCLAlertView().showError(Constants.priceRequired, subTitle: Constants.messagePriceRequired)
            return
        }
        guard let productDescription = productDescriptionTextView.text, productDescription != ""else{
            SCLAlertView().showError(Constants.descriptionRequired, subTitle: Constants.messageDescriptionRequired)
            return
        }

        let product = Product(context: context) // Start inserting in Core Data
        let productUUID = UUID().uuidString
        product.id = productUUID
        product.name = productName
        product.category = productCategory
        product.price = Float(productPrice)!
        product.prodDescription = productDescription

        appDelegate.saveContext() // End inserting and save the content in Core Data
        resetAllFields()
        SCLAlertView().showSuccess(Constants.done, subTitle: Constants.messageProductAdded)
    }
}


// UNIT TESTING

import XCTest
@testable import ShoppingLand

class AdminPanelViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var collection: AdminPanelViewController!

    // Test if ProductNameTextfield is empty
    func testIfProductNameTextfieldIsEmpty(){

        guard let productNameTextField = collection.productNameTextfield else{
            XCTFail("Product name is required !")
            return
        }
        productNameTextField.text = ""

        XCTAssertEqual(productNameTextField.text, "Product name is required !")
    }

}
```

Thank you so much for your time if you are reading this !

Comment: Make sure you're calling `XCUIApplication().launch()` before you do any tests on view controllers.

Comment: Just curious if you initialized AdminPanelController in XCTestCase life cycle setup() method..?

Comment: Did you set the `var collection: AdminPanelViewController!`? It is possible that `collection` could be `nil`?

Comment: I tried all your answers. Is not working with any :(

Comment: can you add your testing code?